# Javascript Redirect Out Of Iframe Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have tried to research it, but I think something might be wrong with my syntax. Below is the attempted code. What I need to do is redirect out of an iframe to another page on the same domain. Header: Location only redirects the iframe, I need the whole page redirected. From other posts I have read, this cannot be done from PHP, but rather requires javascript. This is what I have directly in the PHP right now. Thanks in advance.

```
//header("Location: http://propertytaxdfw.com/CurrentWebsite/error.php?msg=".$httpParsedResponseAr['L_LONGMESSAGE0']);
                $ErrorUrl = 'http://propertytaxdfw.com/CurrentWebsite/error.php?msg=".$httpParsedResponseAr['L_LONGMESSAGE0']';
                <script type="text/javascript">parent.location = '<?php echo $ErrorUrl?>';</script>
```

Comment: You didn't add `<?php` and `?>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `parent.location`?

```
<?php
$ErrorUrl = 'http://propertytaxdfw.com/CurrentWebsite/error.php';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">parent.location = '<?php echo $ErrorUrl?>';</script>
```